# How to quantify nature-likeness/criticality/complexity of image based on its image-statistics in code? openCV examples?

Tags: python, information-theory, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to come up with an image statistic that quantifies the criticality of an image.
Criticality is a scale that is highest when an image finds itself on a sweet spot between randomness (e.g. white-noise) and pure order (e.g. only one solid surface). This metric could indicate whether an image appears more nature-like, or are more salient to people.

Something like FID (Frechet Inception Distance) kind of comes close to it, but I think there could be something more elegant based purely on image statistics, or combining a few statistics. Maybe if you have a background in information theory this could be interesting. Any suggestions?

OpenCV implementations score bonus points.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Aaronson has a nice survey paper "[Quantifying the Rise and Fall of Complexity in Closed Systems](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/coffee2.pdf)" on several related approaches to formally defining complexity in a way which matches intuition - as opposed to Kolmogorov complexity$^1$ (the minimum description length of some data), which is maximized when the data is random bits.

Kolmogorov *sophistication* measures this by factoring out from the data $x$ a "non-random part" $S$. In particular, we say $S$ is a set of similar looking instances of which $x$ is one member. There has to be a constraint that $K(S) + \log_2 |S| \leq K(x) + c$, which prevents us from picking a trivial $S$ for low-complexity strings. Then, the sophistication of $x$ is the smallest $K(S)$ which satisfies our constraint.

To make a long story short, Scott Aaronson describes an extremely crude way to compute sophistication for images: define $S$ to be the set of images which look the same as $x$ when downsampled in resolution by some factor, and estimate it's Kolmogorov complexity -- so basically, downsample $x$ and (losslessly) compress it, and measure the resulting size.

Practically, this assigns nearly 0 sophistication to a totally blank image, or to random noise (which, when downsampled, averages out to grey everywhere). What maximizes sophistication is random noise, but on the same scale as downsampling -- e.g. if you downsample by a factor of 5 to estimate sophistication, having each 5x5 block of pixels being a random color maximizes this measurement.

---

$^1$ A quick description of [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) $K(x)$ is that it's the length of the shortest computer program which can generate/print out an exact copy of your data $x$. A simple way to compute an upper bound on $K(x)$ is 1. pick your favorite compression algorithm, compress $x$. 2. take the size of the compressed content, add it to the size of the algorithm used to compress it (although often, the length of the algorithm may be omitted..) - and this is your upper bound.

---

A totally different approach might be to just compute the power spectrum of a bunch of natural images. I'd guess that the general shape of the power spectrum of natural images would be pretty distinct from many types of "artificial images".

Comment: This is a very relevant paper reccommendation! Even the application of cellular automata is exactly what I'm applying it to. Cheers